# How to write sql query from below condition in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

Here, One table name is blind_dates
[blind_dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E0Dg.png)
[free_paid_dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ6m7.png)

currant logged user id is 611 from user table

so I want to merge data  from blind_dates and free_paid_dated based on user id in one array.
also I want to_user_id information on this array.

Comment: Could you please place the result of those images as text in your question? As a general rule we use that on StackOverflow to make sure the information of the questions are available and accessible.

Comment: I think you're looking to [join two tables](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-perform-inner-join-of-two-tables-in-laravel-query).

Comment: can you plz show expected out? I means to say what kind of data you want to fetch from it?

Comment: Without the table structure, it is hard to answer, but if the structure of both tables is similar, you can use Laravel Union https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions